# Building latest Spark Snapshot in Intellij gives MesosSchedulerBackend compilation errors

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, apache-spark

I ran

```
sbt gen-idea
```

And then I opened the newly created IJ project.  Syntax highlighting is working fine - a good sign.  But there are a handful of errors occurring:

```
C:\apps\incubator-spark\core\src\main\scala\org\apache\spark\executor\MesosExecutorBackend.scala
Error:(256, 35) type mismatch;
 found   : org.apache.mesos.protobuf.ByteString
 required: com.google.protobuf.ByteString
      .setData(ByteString.copyFrom(task.serializedTask))
                                  ^
Error:(119, 35) type mismatch;
 found   : org.apache.mesos.protobuf.ByteString
 required: com.google.protobuf.ByteString
      .setData(ByteString.copyFrom(createExecArg()))
                                  ^
C:\apps\incubator-spark\core\src\main\scala\org\apache\spark\scheduler\cluster\mesos\MesosSchedulerBackend.scala
Error:(44, 35) type mismatch;
 found   : org.apache.mesos.protobuf.ByteString
 required: com.google.protobuf.ByteString
      .setData(ByteString.copyFrom(data))
                                  ^
```

Note that the build IS working on the command line via

```
sbt compile
```

Anyone out there building Spark with Intellij have any suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spark mailing list provided an answer/workaround: the mesos-1.8.jar should be manually removed from IJ.  The mesos-1.8-shared.jar is the correct one and should be retained).

Comment: Thankyou! In my case I had to remove "mesos-0.18.1.jar" and keep "mesos-0.18.1-shaded-protobuf.jar". I also got less intelligible exceptions: stuff like "AssertionFailed" errors in the SBT compiler when trying to find protobuf classes.

Comment: @Neil  For the assertion failed you need to do a "clean".  I do not know why, but that's life.

Comment: @Neil  BTW since this Q&A helped you would you mind to consider to upvote them?